# Boolean OR in sed regex

Tags: regex, sed, logical-operators

I'm trying to replace all references of a package named `boots` in a configuration file.

The line format is `add fast (package OR pkg) boots-(any-other-text)`, e.g.:

```
add fast package boots-2.3
add fast pkg boots-4.5
```

I want to replace it with:

```
add yinst pkg boots-5.0
```

I've tried the following `sed` commands:

```
sed -e 's/add fast (pkg\|package) boots-.*/add yinst pkg boots-5.0/g'
sed -e 's/add fast [pkg\|package] boots-.*/add yinst pkg boots-5.0/g'
```

What's the right regex? I think I'm missing something in the boolean or (`package` or `pkg`) part.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/add fast \(pkg\|package\) boots-.*/add yinst pkg boots-5.0/g'
```

You could always avoid the OR by doing it twice

```
sed 's/add fast pkg boots-.*/add yinst pkg boots-5.0/g
s/add fast package boots-.*/add yinst pkg boots-5.0/g'
```

Comment: It's better to use semi colon in "twice" command. Like this: `sed 's/\.ism/\.ism\.md5/g;s/\.usp/\.usp\.md5/g' /tmp/verify`

Comment: @EvgeniyYablokov Any particular reason? Perhaps in short throwaway scripts (like this one) you may have a point, but I still think the two-line version is easier to read.

Comment: I'm using the GNU-utils version on Windows @ had to do as @EvgeniyYablokov suggested with the semi-colon for it to work.

Answer (score 35):

Use extended regex mode, and don't escape the `|`.

```
sed -E -e 's/add fast (pkg|package) boots-.*/add yinst pkg boots-5.0/g'
```

Comment: `sed: invalid option -- E`. Doesn't seem to work with `GNU sed version 4.1.5` on Red Hat.

Comment: @AdamMatan Ah, use the `-r` flag for GNU sed, as Thor indicates.

Comment: On mac os I got `sed: 1: "-E ": invalid command code -` using `sed -e -E`. Switching parameter it worked fine: `sed -E -e`

Comment: `brew install gnu-sed && gsed --version`... but don't replace it for the whole system as poorly programs that depend on MacOS having a "stable" shell environment will break... also your changes are usually destroyed with ever minor update.

Answer (score 9):

You're mixing BRE's and ERE's either escape both `()` and `|` or none.

sed uses basic regular expressions by default, enabling use of extended regular expressions is implementation dependent, e.g. with BSD sed you use the `-E` switch, GNU sed has it documented as `-r`, but `-E` works as well.

Answer (score 1):

GNU (Linux):

1) Make following random strings

```
   cidr="192.168.1.12"
   cidr="192.168.1.12/32"
   cidr="192.168.1.12,8.8.8.8"
```

to blank

2) sed with -r  for using the logical operators in GNU like @Thor mentioned, and -i to on the fly edit a file on match found

```
$ echo '<user id="1000" cidr="192.168.1.12">' > /tmp/1000.xml
$ sed -r -i \ 
  s/'cidr="192.168.1.12\/32"|cidr="192.168.1.12"|192.168.1.12,'/''/ /tmp/1000.xml

-r = GNU sed
-i = search / match/ edit the changes to the file on the fly
```