# Removing specific character from anywhere between two specific strings?

Tags: regex, parsing, sed

I have a large text file that contains content as per the below example:

```
number="+123 123 123" text="This is some text"
number="+123456" text="This may contain numbers"
number="+123456 789" text="Numbers here should keep their spaces"
number="+9 8 7 6 5" text="example 123 123 123"
```

What I would like is to remove any whitespace character between two identifying strings, in this case `number=` and `" text=` without touching the rest of the line. So that the desired output would be:

```
number="+123123123" text="This is some text"
number="+123456" text="This may contain numbers"
number="+123456789" text="Numbers here should keep their spaces"
number="+98765" text="example 123 123 123"
```

A regex like `(?<=[0-9])(\s)(?=[0-9])` will interfere with with text field, which is undesirable.

I have tested a few variations of using something along the lines of `(?<=address)(\s)(?=date)` but this doesn't work. I think the problem lies in not being able to deal with the extra possible numbers in between the whitespace and the markers?

Adding wildcard matches into the lookbehinds/lookaheads such as `(?<=address.*)(\s)(?=.*date)` doesn't seem valid or else I've done it wrong? Also making the whitespace lazy with `(/s+?)` doesn't seem to help me, but this is about where my knowledge of regex really falls to pieces :)

Ideally I would also like to restrict between the extra equals and quotes characters for safety. I.e `number="` at the beginning marker and `text="` as the end marker.

Any sed/awk or similar solutions are also welcomed if easier.

Comment: Can there be number elsewhere on the line that should be shorten, except the one directly after `number="+`? Example `number="+123 123 123" text="This is some text" number2="+435 234 132`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a substitution and a loop:

```
sed ':l s/\(number="[^" \t]*\)\s\s*/\1/g;tl' input
```

this one gives:

```
number="+123123123" text="This is some text"
number="+123456" text="This may contain numbers"
number="+123456789" text="Numbers here should keep their spaces"
number="+98765" text="example 123 123 123"
```

Comment: +1; the `g` is not necessary, though. Assumes _GNU_ `sed`. For POSIX compliance, use `sed -e ':l' -e 's/\(number="[^" \t]*\) \{1,\}/\1/;tl' input`.

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""}{gsub(/ /,"",$2)}1' file
number="+123123123" text="This is some text"
number="+123456" text="This may contain numbers"
number="+123456789" text="Numbers here should keep their spaces"
number="+98765" text="example 123 123 123"
```

Comment: I do like the `awk` before the `sed` solution, since its much more readable. Some golfing to make it a bit shorter: `awk -F\" '{gsub(/ /,"",$2)}1' OFS=\" file`

Answer (score 2):

**Search:**  `[ ](?=[^"]*" text=)` (the `[brackets]` around the space are optional, they are there for clarity)

**Replace:** empty string.

In [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/26), see the substitutions at the bottom.

**Command-Line Syntax**

I don't know the sed syntax to search and replace. With Perl (courtesy of @jaypal and @AvinashRaj):

```
perl -pe 's/ (?=[^"]*" text=)//g' file
```

From `perl --help`,

```
-p                assume loop like -n but print line also, like sed
-e program        one line of program (several -e's allowed, omit programfile)
```

Comment: No, it's not possible through sed.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I don't know sed. Can you please explain which part is not possible?

Comment: In sed `|` considered as a delimiter not as an logical operator.

Comment: @zx81 The look ahead is not possible but you can certainly use `perl` and no Avinash `|` is not just a delimiter. It is also a logical operator.

Comment: @jaypal does `|` symbol works as an logical operator in  sed?

Comment: @jaypal Thanks for your comments. I don't use these command-line tools apart from grep, so don't know the syntax to incorporate my search-and-replace

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813145/boolean-or-in-sed-regex) is an SO question but you can also look it up in the [guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions). It does not however support logical `AND` operator.

Comment: But it isn't support lookahead.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Correct, I did mention that in my comments earlier to zx81.

Comment: @zx81 Here is a `perl` using your `regex` for completeness `;)`. `perl -pe 's/(text="[^"]*")| (?=[^"]*" text=)/$1/g' file`. Very crafty `regex` +1

Comment: @AvinashRaj Well done, well spotted! That regex evolved from an earlier version that didn't have the lookahead, and I didn't stop to think and realize that we no longer needed the expression on the left. Thank you. :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj For completion, wWould you kindly give me the `awk` and `sed` equivalents using the same regex? I know you know them. :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj No doubts, you're the pro, don't know the first thing about awk and sed. :)

Comment: @zx81 `awk` is usually meant to be used as a field splitter. But if you really want to max out then you can use `GNU awk` and do `gawk '{while((new=gensub(/([[:digit:]]+)(\s)([[:digit:]]+)(\" text=)/,"\\1\\3\\4","g")) != $0) $0=new}1' file`.

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` solution:

```
 awk -F ' text="' '{ gsub(/ /, "", $1); print $1 FS $2 }' file
```

- `-F text="'` splits each input line into the part before `text="` (`$1`), and the part after (`$2`) - the `-F` option sets the special `FS` (*f*ield *s*eparator) `awk` variable to  a regex that `awk` uses to split each input line into fields.
- `gsub(/ /, "", $1)` (*g*lobal *sub*stitution) removes all spaces from `$1` (the part before `text="`; replaces spaces with the empty string).
- `print $1 FS $2` prints the output: the *modified* `$1` (spaces removed), joined with `FS` (i.e., `text="`), joined with `$2` (the unmodified part after `text="`).

Answer (score 1):

Note: This is a **complement to the existing answers** to **compare their performance**.

**Test environments**:

- OS X 10.9.4.

  - FreeBSD awk 20070501
  - FreeBSD sed (cannot tell version number)
  - Perl v5.16.2
- Ubuntu 14.04

  - GNU Awk 4.0.1
  - sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
  - Perl v5.18.2

The **short of it**:

- The `awk` solutions are *fastest*.

  - On OS X, [@jaypal's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24689356/45375) is faster, on Ubuntu it's [@mklement0's (mine)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24689380/45375).
- Followed by the [`perl` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24689339/45375).
- The [`sed` solution (accepted answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24689325/45375) is *slowest*.

  - Note that removing the unnecessary `g` option *does* improve things measurably, but doesn't change the big picture.

On OS X, the differences aren't dramatic.
On Ubuntu, the differences between the `awk` and the `perl` solutions are small, but the `sed` solution is dramatically slower.

Sample numbers, running against a 100,000-line input file 10 times.
Don't compare them directly (Ubuntu is running in a VM on the OS X machine), just look at their ratios. (Curiously, though, `awk` and `perl` ran *faster* in the Ubuntu VM):

OS X:

```
# awk (@japyal)
real    0m3.848s
user    0m3.773s
sys 0m0.049s

# awk (@mklement0)
real    0m4.011s
user    0m3.959s
sys 0m0.045s

# perl
real    0m4.382s
user    0m4.291s
sys 0m0.063s

# sed
real    0m4.867s
user    0m4.816s
sys 0m0.044s

# sed  (no `g`)
real    0m4.510s
user    0m4.460s
sys 0m0.044s
```

Ubuntu:

```
# awk (@mklement0)
real    0m1.850s
user    0m1.788s
sys 0m0.020s

# awk (@jaypal)
real    0m2.055s
user    0m1.996s
sys 0m0.012s

# perl
real    0m2.349s
user    0m2.276s
sys 0m0.024s

# sed
real    0m8.278s
user    0m8.196s
sys 0m0.016s

# sed (no `g`)
real    0m7.580s
user    0m7.488s
sys 0m0.028s
```

Comment: @jaypal: My pleasure; I had a hunch that the `sed` solution would be slow due to the loop. I find the platform differences interesting.

Comment: The sed and perl solutions are slower due to regex usage, lot of back tracking (perl) and loop(sed). I'm more curious with the difference in awk, though it's fairly close.

Comment: @jaypal: Good points; just ran with `mawk` on Ubuntu, your solution is again the faster one (not by much), and both finish in less than a _third_ of the time compared to `gawk` - interesting how much faster `mawk` is. With these `awk` solutions, `mawk` inside my VM runs about 7 times as fast FreeBSD `awk` on the host machine...